# Activating a class with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

The problem is that the class only works one time.

css

```
    .green-glow {
    animation-name: green-glow;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes green-glow {
    0% {
        border: 4px solid rgba(67, 243, 97);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #31b43a;
    }
    50% {
        border: 4px solid rgba(21, 255, 0, 0.822);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #29f036;
    }
    100% {
        border: 4px solid rgba(13, 255, 45, 0.685);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #31b43a;
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {
    const result =  document.getElementById('p_result');
    result.textContent = 'You Win!';
    userScore++;
    userScore_span.textContent = userScore;
    document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.add('green-glow')
}
```

i want to activate the class: "green glow" every time the user wins.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Provide the html also please

Comment: What is "something"?

Comment: When do you want to add this class?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't completely reproduce your case epically about `userChoice, computerChoice` 
but made a sample for you hope it will help

```js
function winUser() {
  document.getElementById("user").classList.add("green-glow");
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("user").classList.remove("green-glow");
  }, 1000); // animation time
}

function winPc() {
  document.getElementById("pc").classList.add("green-glow");
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("pc").classList.remove("green-glow");
  }, 1000); // animation time
}
```

```css
.green-glow {
    animation-name: green-glow;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes green-glow {
    0% {
        border: 4px solid rgba(67, 243, 97);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #31b43a;
    }
    50% {
        border: 4px solid rgba(21, 255, 0, 0.822);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #29f036;
    }
    100% {
        border: 4px solid rgba(13, 255, 45, 0.685);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #31b43a;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div id="user">User</div>
  <div id="pc">PC</div>
</div>

<button onclick="winUser()">Win User</button>
<button onclick="winPc()">Win PC</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the cotation!

```js
   var element = document.getElementById("userChoice");
   element.classList.add("green-glow");
```